# Error in is.data.frame(data) : object 'test_data' not found

Tags: r, model, runtime-error, data-science, logistic-regression

I am new in to R programming and trying creating Logistic Regression model for the first time.
While creating the model, I am getting the below error:

```
m<-glm(ad~.,data=test_data,family='binomial')
Error in terms.formula(formula, data = data) : 
  '.' in formula and no 'data' argument
```

Code:

```
college<- read.csv(file.choose(),header=T)

head(college)
```

[image]

```
set.seed(2020)
split_data<- sample.split(college_final$admit,SplitRatio=3/4)
split_data

train_data<- subset(split_data,split==T)
train_data
test_data<-subset(split_data,split==F)
test_data

model<-glm(admit~.,data=test_data,family='binomial')
model
summary(model)
```

Tried looking into R community for the same, but nothing was mentioned about it.

Comment: Added summary of the dataset above

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough rep to leave a comment. But I tried to reproduce the data and it showed an error when I was creating `test_data`, so I think the issue is with subsetting. (I wonder if you got an error?)

In this case, we want test_data to be a data frame instead of vector. Try `str(test_data)` to see if it returns `data.frame`.

If not, try replacing

```
train_data<- subset(split_data,split==T)
test_data<-subset(split_data,split==F)
```

With

```
train_data <- subset(college, split_data == T)
test_data <- subset(college, split_data == F)
```

And run `glm` again.

Comment: Hi Daisy, thanks for the solution. It got resolved with performing the second suggestion.